# resizeToAvoidBottomPadding isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

After I update my flutter with command `flutter pub upgrade`, this function  isn't defined anymore, any solution for this..[image]

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, actually, there is a comment inside of the [API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html).

> This flag is deprecated. Please use resizeToAvoidBottomInset instead.

So the idea would be to replace the behaviour as stated [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html).

resizeToAvoidBottomInset param definition:

If true the [body] and the scaffold's floating widgets should size
themselves to avoid the onscreen keyboard whose height is defined by the
ambient [MediaQuery]'s [MediaQueryData.viewInsets] `bottom` property.
For example, if there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the
scaffold, the body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard, which
prevents widgets inside the body from being obscured by the keyboard.